# Gurobipy: matrix constraints

Tags: python, optimization, gurobi, integer-programming

Let `x` be the vector of n variables defined with: `x = M.addMVar(shape = n, vtype = GRB.BINARY, name = "x")`. Let `A` be an n by n matrix. Let `v` be an n by 1 constant vector that consists of positive integers. The constraint that I am interested in:

`np.multiply(v, x) <= A @ x`

However, when I add this constraint in gurobi:

`M.addConstr(np.multiply(v, x) <= A @ x, name = "c1")`

It gives errors:

> File "src/gurobipy/model.pxi", line 3325, in gurobipy.Model.addConstr
>
> File "src/gurobipy/model.pxi", line 3586, in gurobipy.Model.addMConstr
>
> TypeError: must be real number, not MLinExpr

Any idea why this happening? I have been working on a solution for hours. My current guess is that Gurobi is not happy with variables occurring on both sides of the inequality. However, I haven't figured out a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not work because the matrix representation in the Gurobi Python interface requires the canonical form Ax = b. So you need to incorporate v into the A matrix, and your code becomes something like:

```
A2 = A-v*np.eye(n)
M.addConstr(A2 @ x >= 0)
```